# Completion for frame local variables from backtrace

Tags: debugging, emacs, code-completion, backtrace

I'm trying to add completion at point for frame-local variables from `backtrace-frames` during invocations of `read--expression` by `debugger-eval-expression` or `edebug-eval-expression`.

I constructed the following completion table to add frame-local variables to the already available table for local elisp variables,

```
;; completion table for locals in current frame
(defvar my-backtrace-locals-completion-table
  (completion-table-in-turn
   (completion-table-dynamic
    (lambda (_string)
      (when-let* ((idx (backtrace-get-index))  ;backtrace.el
                  (frame (nth idx backtrace-frames)))
        (backtrace-frame-locals frame)))
    'do-switch-buffer)
   elisp--local-variables-completion-table))   ;elisp-mode.el
```

which seems to work fine, eg. to reproduce

(1) evaluate

```
;; debug-on-error = t
(let ((my-local-var '(1 2))) (mapcan #'car this-local-var))
```

(2) from debugger's second frame, evaluate with `eval-expression`

```
(funcall my-backtrace-locals-completion-table "my-" nil t)
```

returns expected `("my-local-var")`.

The problem is following the above steps, but calling instead calling `debugger-eval-expression` doesn't work.  The environment where the table is evaluated isn't finding a `backtrace-frame` (with or without `do-switch-buffer`).

How can I define the table to be evaluated in the proper buffer?

emacs v27.0.50

Answer (score 0):

The completion table above doesn't quite return the expected candidates for `debugger-eval-expression`.  The environment where the expression is evaluated has locals from frames higher than, but not including, the one at point in the *Backtrace* buffer.

So, the available locals should be only those from higher frames, eg.

```
(eval-when-compile (require 'dash))
(defvar my-backtrace-locals-completion-table
  (completion-table-dynamic
   (lambda (_string)
     (when backtrace-frames
       (--mapcat
        (-some->> (backtrace-frame-locals it) (--map (car it)))
        (nthcdr (1+ (backtrace-get-index)) backtrace-frames))))
   'do-switch-buffer))
```

Then, redefining `debugger-eval-expression`'s interactive spec to use the new locals table in place of the normal elisp table provides the correct completions (passing the `'do-switch-buffer` arg `completion-table-dynamic` to find completions in the original buffer).

```
(defun my-backtrace@eval (orig-fn exp &optional nframe)
  (interactive
   (let ((elisp--local-variables-completion-table
          my-backtrace-locals-completion-table))
     (list (read--expression "[my] Eval in stack frame: "))))
  (apply orig-fn (list exp nframe)))

(advice-add 'debugger-eval-expression :around #'my-backtrace@eval)
```